# Is it possible to query both X and Y coordinates of an object via inkscape command line?

Tags: inkscape

You can do this:

```
inkscape --query-id="myid" --query-x "D:\mydrawing.svg"
```

And it will print X coordinate of the object with given ID.

You can also do this:

```
inkscape --query-id="myid" --query-y "D:\mydrawing.svg"
```

And it will print Y coordinate instead. But trying to get both coordinates only returns X:

```
inkscape --query-id="myid" --query-x --query-y "D:\mydrawing.svg"
```

Is there a way to get both coordinates? I'm running inkscape from Node.js and each call takes almost 1.5s, so I'd rather not call inkscape twice for both coordinates.

Comment: There's a [query-all](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/CommandLine-Query.html) option which returns x, y, width and height. You can parse x and y from there.

Comment: But that returns info for all nodes.